# Saving OfficeJS Add-In state across all documents?

Tags: office365, office365api, office-js, office365-apps

I know that I can save Add-In state per document using document.settings.

Is there a way to save state (e.g. active license) across documents for the same Add-In?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you save user state depends on your needs.

If you want to track **per-machine state** you can save the data in [HTML5 Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

If you want to track **per-user state for signed-in users** (no matter what machine or document they use), you should save their User ID and state on your database. For my own add-in, I implemented this design with [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/):

```js
function readUserStateAsync(customerId, callback){
    var myUserReference = firebase.database().ref("myCustomers/" + customerId);
    myUserReference.once('value').then(function(userState) {
        callback(userState.val());
    });
}

function writeUserStateAsync(customerId, userState, callback){
    var myUserReference = firebase.database().ref("myCustomers");
    myUserReference.child(customerId).set(userState, function(){ callback("success"); });
}
```

-Michael Saunders, program manager for Office add-ins

Answer (score 1):

To add to Michael Saunders' answer:  you can also get a unique ID for the signed-in Office user (or more specifically, to the user identity who acquired the add-in):  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164035.aspx

Comment: I read that complex page, but is there a way to simply get a unique user ID using JavaScript so I can send it to my server?  My goal is to store user-specific information on my server so that user can use the info across different documents and hosts as long as they have the add-in installed.  I'd prefer not to require an added log-in.

Comment: @ExcelAnalyst, the "cid" field of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163880.aspx is a *reasonably* good value to use.  There are several caveats, though.  a) It may sometimes be empty (if the add-in was bought on behalf of the organization, or if the user is somehow not signed in with a Microsoft Account).  b) it is not guaranteed to stay the same forever (that's what the validation-returned ID is guaranteed to be, whereas the cid one might someday change if the hashing algorithm changes).  But, when not empty, it's a pretty good indicator of same user.

Comment: PS:  To be clear, the **converse** of the last statement would not be true.  I.e., different cid values do NOT necessarily mean different users (could be different hashes of the same user, over a long enough period of time).  But same CID value -- I think -- will [almost] always mean the same user.  If you need a guarantee, though, you'll need to use the server-side validation.

Comment: One other note:  in Office 2016, users can actually acquire free add-in anonymously.  So in those cases, the "cid" field could be empty.